# How to connect viewcontroller to NSObject class file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to connect and pass the action from ViewController to NSObject class file. In my viewcontroller, there is UISwitch Button and if I switch I want to work it in NSObject class file.

When switch is ON from viewcontroller (UIView) then the action have to work in NSObject class file.

I'm coding with Objective-C.

Here is my ***ViewController.m*** and I did this in only ViewController file. Not connected to NSOBject class file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

//UISwitch work at viewDidload

[self.mySwitch addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(stateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; }


- (void)stateChanged:(UISwitch *)switchState{

NSLog(@"current calendar: %@", [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] calendarIdentifier]);
//get the date today
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Today Date is: %@", [NSDate date]);
self.myLabel.text=dateToday;

if ([switchState isOn]) {

    //[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US@calendar=japanese"]];
    [formatter setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierJapanese]];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    UILabel *dtDate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 20.0f)];
    [dtDate setText:dateToday];

    self.myLabel.text =dateToday;
    NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"current date is: %@", dateToday);
    NSLog(@"current locale: %@", locale);

} else {

    //[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 20.0f)];
    [myLabel setText:dateToday];

    self.myLabel.text =dateToday;
    //        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"current locale: %@", locale);
    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just an action then use class methods else create a global variable or a notification observer in NSObject extended class when you get call back from the switch.

```
- (void)callback:(id)sender
 {
     [MyObject switchState:sender.state];
 }
```

Comment: I used as you said. but the error found. I use it in NSObject class file as

- (void)callback:(id)sender
{
    [NSObject switchState:sender.state];
}

Then the error show as - Property `state` note found on object of type `__strong id`

Thanks for your answer. Can you please detail. I'm just the starter in iOS.

Comment: Create a new class which extends from NSObject in that add switch state class method in it.

Comment: If you simply need to trigger the action in the NSObject class, set the self.mySwitch's addTarget to your NSObject subclass's object and define stateChanged: method in that NSObject subclass.